# gulp-ruby-sass skipping imported files

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

For some reason whenever I run my gulp styles task using gulp-ruby-sass it only pulls in the first file in a folder that actually has style declarations (as opposed to declaring variables or setting up mixins) and then skips the rest of the imports.

This is my folder structure

```
\scss  
    style.scss (imports all of the main files in partial folders)  
    \folder1  
        _main1.scss (imports all other files in the folder)  
        _variables.scss  
        _mixins.scss  
        _somestyle.scss  
        _somestyle2.scss  
        _somestyle3.scss  
    \folder2  
        _main2.scss (imports all other files in the folder)  
        _variables.scss  
        _mixins.scss  
        _somestyle.scss  
        _somestyle2.scss  
        _somestyle3.scss
```

Whenever I run the task only the first _somestyle.scss of each folder is compiled. Every other file in the folder is skipped. This is verified by my .css.map which shows the variable and mixin files in the source as well as the first file with style declarations. Then it skips to the next folder.

I don't think this is a load path issue since at least one file is included in every subfolder and I've tried running in the task with load path included.

I am also not getting any errors during compile. I'm at a loss.

Here is my gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
gulp.src(source+'scss/style.scss')//Imports all other scss files
    .pipe(sass({
        // Tried loadPath here it didn't change anything
        style: 'expanded',
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(source+'css'))
    .pipe(cmq())
    .pipe(notify({message: 'Styles compiled'}));
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.